# How to search for a phrase within a file with Windows Search SDK?

Tags: c#, windows, search

I'm using Windows Search SDK.
I need to search for an OrderId inside a list of files (I do not know where it is...).
I took microsoft sample i see how to search in file name, date, type etc. but not in contents...
Please advise

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm using Windows Search SDK - It has many properties to search by
(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404235.aspx)
But I do not which one can search inside text file (in my case xml...)